# How to add 5 minute to a 24h format time in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have 24h format time array in javascript:

var time = ['04:32', '05:47', '11:55', '15:21', '18:02', '18:02', '19:12', '23:54'];

I want to add 5 or 10 minute to every value inside the array and return 12hr format time with am or pm add at the end of each value.

Comment: hm, i have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262911/how-to-add-5-minutes-to-a-24h-format-time) today ... anyway. what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz, maybe he can't view deleted questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a two pass method to get first the time with an additional minute count and then the adjusted value with [am/pm time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock).

```js
function format(v) { return ('0' + v).slice(-2); }

function add(minutes) {
    return function (t) {
        var m = t.split(':').reduce(function (h, m) {  return 60 * h + +m; });
        m += minutes;
        return [Math.floor(m / 60) % 24, m % 60].map(format).join(':');
    };
}

function am(t) {
    var v = t.split(':');
    return [v[0] % 12 || 12, v[1]].map(format).join(':') + (v[0] < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm');
}

var time = ['04:32', '05:47', '11:55', '15:21', '18:02', '18:02', '19:12', '23:54'],
    result = time
        .map(add(5))
        .map(am);

console.log(result);

// using a single value
console.log(am(add(5)('11:56')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. You are awesome in javascript. The functions are little complicated to me but works for the array. Can you please give me the functions if the time is not array but just a veriable. like var time = '11:56';

Comment: Many Thanks. I figured it out.